# how to set up proxy pass or iptables for ssh?

Tags: ssh, networking, iptables, nginx, proxy

I tried to set up a nginx server for my pi's at home. The problem was, the dyndns take too long to update. therefore I can't access my gitolite server.

So instead of using dyndns, I set up a ec2 instance. every traffic that go to my domains, will using this ec2 ip. from there, I use nginx to moderate traffic to my pi's. I got it working pretty well with http and https server. and I can also set up a stream server to my ssh. Now come the problem. From what I read, the ssh protocol doesn't give the dns. Well I am not an sysadmin, so maybe the terms I used were incorrect.

I install fail2ban in my pi. every ssh traffic go through the nginx server, using the same ip. and then when it got blocked by the fail2ban. I can't access them at all.

for them who want to use nginx. Im not recommended, but this is working.

```
stream {
    upstream ssh {
        server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22;
    }

    server {
        listen        22;
        proxy_pass    ssh;
    }            

    upstream ssh {
        server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2288;
    }

    server {
        listen        2288;
        proxy_pass    ssh;
    }

}
```

This is only working for nginx ^1.2 I guess.

I tried all the possible config:

```
#   proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
#   proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
#   proxy_set_header Host $host;
#   proxy_protocol on;
```

none of them pass the ip. Maybe someone know what is wrong with the configurations?

I read also some suggestion to use iptables instead. and then i tried all the one below:

```
#iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth4 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22
#iptables -A FORWARD -i eth4 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
#iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d xx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELAT$
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244

#iptables -A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d xx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 22 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELAT$
#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244
```

I am not sure, why it is not working. -i eth4 -o eth1 i guess this one is the networking isn't it, including the ppp0? My pi only has one eth0.

can someone tell me, what is the problem here? can I used the same port for out and in? or it has to be different port at all? Some explanations about the iptables config would be helpful.

Thank you!